# Is there a function in Android Studio to automatically adjust the layout to the display size?

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-size

I'm in the process of creating a small questionnaire. Although all views are constrained, the individual text views overlap or slide to the edge.

So far I have only created the design for the layout and have not yet linked any functions with anything. When I display the layout on a larger display, everything is shown as it should be.

Can someone help me and tell me how I can design my layout so that it automatically adjusts to the display size?

I'm really new about programming in Android and don't know all the backgrounds I may have disregarded.

I tried to use the `AutoSizeMaxText` fuction but I'm not sure if I used it the right way.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such thing as an automatic function to support different screen sizes.

What you can do:

1. Use constraintLayout
2. Use `match_parent` and `wrap_content` instead of hard-coded sizes in your xml
3. Create different layouts for almost every (if not every) screen resolution: 
   ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi
4. Use stretchable nine-patch bitmaps for image resources.
5. Consider using fragments and double-pane structure for large devices

You may want to chek this library: https://github.com/intuit/sdp

and this one for text size: https://github.com/intuit/ssp

Don't forget to test it in as many devices with different resolutions and pixel density as you can.

You can check the official documentation for this issue: [Android developers: Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)